# How do you properly "unblank" (as in exit screensaver) a console on a server?

Tags: console, screensaver

I had this server which after 10 minutes would blank the screen and the monitor would go into sleep mode.

I added `consoleblank=0` to the kernel parameters in order to avoid this.

My main issue with it is that I'm not sure how to wake up the screen. As I understand it, a keyboard interaction is necessary to archive this, but what if I don't know what is running behind the blank screen? It could be a prompt waiting for a key press in order to execute some command.

What is the proper way to unblank the screen with the keyboard with a guarantee that this will not be interpreted as input by any program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.  "Modifier" keys do not cause actions to be performed, except in some games.

- If someone leaves their game idle / unpaused for ten minutes, they are not seriously concerned about it.
- In the case of a server text console, you are probably not concerned with games.

[A lot of people use this trick](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ZaEePYR8LIsC&pg=PA306&lpg=PA306&dq=what+key+should+I+use+to+safely+unblank+the+screen?&source=bl&ots=t-PzqCc-Eq&sig=ACfU3U1a9oPLH1Im21dVaXx9sLw8lg87nA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwix0Y6y-5_pAhWHjqQKHd7bDtkQ6AEwEXoECAwQAQ#v=onepage&q=what%20key%20should%20I%20use%20to%20safely%20unblank%20the%20screen%3F&f=false).  If software or configuration breaks this assumption, it will be criticized.

Answer (score 3):

There is a private control sequence that can be sent to a kernel virtual terminal (i.e. one of the `/dev/ttyN` devices, not to be confused with the console, `/dev/console`) to unblank the screen.  You can look it up in the `console_codes` manual and just write it to that device with (say) `printf`.

Or you can use the util-linux command that emits the control sequence for you:

```
TERM=linux setterm --blank poke < /dev/tty0
```

In fact, it doesn't emit the control sequence.  It uses a peculiar-to-Linux-KVT-devices `ioctl()` on its standard input.  Yes, standard input.  Really.  Its manual nowhere hints that this is the case for some, but not all, of `setterm`'s functions.  That would be too easy and predictable.

Note that my portable `setterm` does not replicate stuff like this that is peculiar to the Linux built-in terminal emulator.  You need the util-linux one for this.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). [`setterm`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/setterm.xml).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.